# Site with public profile pages

Tags: users, user-profile, profile

I'm looking to try and build a site that allows users to register an account and then add all of their social media profiles in one place, similar to addme.fun. Their profiles would then have public URLs that they could share, and it would also give them the ability to add more content and edit their profiles. Is Craft a good CMS for that?

I've built some really great projects with Craft and overall I love it, but I just want to make sure that it has all the capabilities that I'd need before I put too much time into it. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 2):

Yes craft provides many tools that allows public registration and editing the profiles without a single line of php or even a plugin. Most functions are covered by the cms and even custom functions like social media support is really easy since you can extend the `UserController` and change the things you need.

You have the ability to create dynamic user groups, give permissions to those and restrict content on the site via twig. Like with entries you can define a field layout for every user so you could create all the fields you can create in a normal entry and give users the ability to change them in a frontend form

You have config variables and settings that allows you to send custom invitation mails and validation mails.

But you need the commercial version for this. It's not provided in the free one.